# Link to static boost lib with cmake and vs2010 without automatic linking

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, boost, cmake

I got an app that links to boost_program_options, whose CMakeLists.txt looks like

```
FIND_PACKAGE(Boost COMPONENTS program_options REQUIRED)
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES( ${SUBPROJECT_NAME} ${Boost_LIBRARIES} )
```

I use `#define BOOST_ALL_NO_LIB` in my code before including `<boost/program_options.hpp>` to disable the automatic linking of boost in vs2010, because I want to specify that by cmake to make it compatible with linux.

In Linux, this code compiles just fine (with cmake, make and gcc).
But in Windows with VS2010, I get a

```
2>App.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: static unsigned int const boost::program_options::options_description::m_default_line_length" (?m_default_line_length@options_description@program_options@boost@@2IB)
2>App.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > boost::program_options::arg" (?arg@program_options@boost@@3V?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@A)
```

Note that the linker finds the lib - if it didn't find it, I would get many more unresolved external errors.

I tracked the problem down to the following:
http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2009/11/54015.php which very nicely describes what's going on (those two are global variables). Now the proposed solution there is to enable dynamic linking and link to the DLLs. But that is not what I'd like to do, I would like to link against the static boost lib (which I'm actually trying to do, in the App properties in VS under Linker->Input it lists `D:\boost\boost_1_47\lib\boost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib`.

I also tried adding

```
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS        ON)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED      ON)
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    OFF)
```

to my CMakeLists.txt but it doesn't change anything.

Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Update:
When linking with boost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_47.lib, I get a whole bunch of new linker errors about CRT-symbols being already defined in the boost-lib. 
After changing the VS Runtime options as suggested by panickal, those errors are also gone and it's working.

Comment: Did you add the 3 `set` calls *before* the `find_package` call?

Comment: Yes, of course. Problem is solved, thanks anyway :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to link to the static library. Try linking to `boost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_47.lib` instead of `boost_program_options-vc100-mt-gd-1_47.lib`.

The `s` indicates the static version of the library. You can check Boost [Library Naming](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#library-naming) for more details about the naming conventions.

Update:
To fix the multiple definition linker errors, change the Visual Studio Runtime Library option in `Configuration Properties / C/C++ / Code Generation / Runtime Library` from  `Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)` to `Multi-threaded Debug (/MTd)`.

Comment: I always thought a .lib file is always a static lib, while a .dll is a dynamic lib. 
The manual says:
"On Windows, .dll indicates a shared library and .lib indicates a static or import library." and further down "Key: s - linking statically to the C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries." I am confused about that now.

Ok, I just set "set(Boost_USE_STATIC_RUNTIME    ON) and the boost error disappears in VS. So the _runtime_ is now built in, I think I start to understand. But I think this is not what one wants? I get a whole bunch of new linker errors now about ...

Comment: "msvcprtd.lib(MSVCP100D.dll) : error LNK2005: "public: ...something... already defined in libboost_program_options-vc100-mt-sgd-1_47.lib".

Comment: On Windows, `.dll` is used for dynamic linking. But you'll have to link with a `.lib` file which contains the required symbols when the program is built. And that `.lib` is different from the `static .lib` file.

Comment: You should link in only one library. Are you getting the new `previously defined` linker errors because of the other library also being linked in.

Comment: I think I'm getting those new errors because I somewhere already include this "C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries", and now, when I link to program_options-vc100-mt-sgd, which is statically linked to this "C++ standard library and compiler runtime support libraries", I guess I'm somehow linking to this runtime library twice and the compiler tells me "Error, function xyz from runtime library already defined in program_options_-vc100-mt-sgd, why do you link to me again?"

Comment: So is this really what I want? Isn't the runtime library from visual studio better than the one boost is linked to? I fear I'm fumbling with things I shouldn't. I don't want to mess with my Visual Studio project's runtime settings. I just want to link to boost...?

Comment: There would not be any issue with Visual Studio runtime settings. The undefined linker problem is because the two variables have not been defined. So to fix this, you've to either enable dynamic linking and link to the DLL, or link to the static library.

Comment: Yes, but linking to the "mt-sgd" library produces all the new linker errors that I described above!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/13149/discussion-between-panickal-and-ela782)

Comment: Everything compiling now. But one thing that came to my mind after reading the last two ours about static/dynamic linking: Don't I have now the problem that the boost mt-sgd lib could use another version of the static CRT, than the one that I am pulling in into my own lib with "/MTd"?
Which can cause some pretty undefined behaviour/crashes?

Comment: I think as long as the versions match(indicated by `vc100` for boost), there would not be any problem.

Comment: Changing the library option as stated here fixed everything for me. Thank you!!